# Responsive menu using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on the responsive menu. when we resize the screen menu items will be appear down is working fine but the problem is onClick on red button is working fine. When I refresh the page all items visible. I want before it will be hidden on click the red button then the menu will appear.
It is coming like this i want to hide overflow menu
[image]

onClick working fine. Before the click, it will be hidden
[image]

[I have taken inspiration from here](http://demo.themerex.net/?theme=monyxi&_ga=2.109913990.2028767309.1545223654-217436162.1545223654)

```js
var h = 30;
var val = 0;

$('.click').click(function() {
  if ($('ul li.menu-item').hasClass('show')) {
    $('ul li.menu-item').removeClass('show');
    $('ul li.menu-item').removeClass('drop')
    return;
  }
  val = 0;
  $('ul li.menu-item').each(function() {
    var of = $(this).offset().top - $('ul li.menu-item').offset().top;
    if ( of > 20) {
      $(this).addClass('drop').css('opcaity', '1');;

      $(this).css('top', 'calc(100% + ' + val + 'px)');
      val += h;
    }
    $('ul li.menu-item').addClass('show');
  })
})
```

```css
.primary-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 64%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hiddin;
  background: #ccc;
}

ul.menu-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #88c0c7;
  position: relative;
}

li.drop {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 52px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-item:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.drop ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36%;
  left: -72%;
}

.click {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  background: red;
  right: -5%;
  top: -2%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Small Desktop Resolution and iPad Landscape
======================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .click {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 2%;
  }
}


/* iPad Portrait
======================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  .click {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 2%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="primary-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item">Home
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="sub-item">menu1</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu2</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">About us</li>
    <li class="menu-item">Service
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="sub-item">menu1</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu2</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">product</li>
    <li class="menu-item">packages</li>
    <li class="menu-item">contact</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu7</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu8</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu9</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu10</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu11
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="sub-item">menu1</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu2</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu12</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu13</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu14
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="sub-item">menu1</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu2</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="click"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Before the button click , just give $('.menu-item').hide();

Comment: @Thanveer Shah I have tried  if `$('.menu-item').hide();` write this complete menu will be hide.

Comment: Wait. so when the screen first loads , You want the sub-menu to be hidden ?

Comment: @ThanveerShah yes I want overflow menu items should be hidden only on click red button I will appear.

Answer (score 2):

hope this will be useful.

```js
var h = 30;
var val = 0;

$('ul li.menu-item').each(function() {
    var of = $(this).offset().top - $('ul li.menu-item').offset().top;
    if ( of > 20) {
      $(this).addClass('hide');
    }
})

$('.click').click(function() {
 if ($('ul li.menu-item').hasClass('hide')) {
    $('ul li.menu-item').removeClass('hide');
  }
  $('ul li.menu-item').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('drop')){
      $(this).addClass('hide');
    }
  });
  
  if ($('ul li.menu-item').hasClass('show')) {
    $('ul li.menu-item').removeClass('show');
    $('ul li.menu-item').removeClass('drop')
    return;
  }
  val = 0;
  $('ul li.menu-item').each(function() {
    var of = $(this).offset().top - $('ul li.menu-item').offset().top;
    if ( of > 20) {
      $(this).addClass('drop').css('opcaity', '1');;

      $(this).css('top', 'calc(100% + ' + val + 'px)');
      val += h;
    }
    $('ul li.menu-item').addClass('show');
  })
})
```

```css
.primary-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hiddin;
  background: #ccc;
}

ul.menu-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #88c0c7;
  position: relative;
}

li.drop {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 52px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-item:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.drop ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36%;
  left: -72%;
}

.click {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  background: red;
  right: -5%;
  top: -2%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Small Desktop Resolution and iPad Landscape
======================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .click {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 2%;
  }
}


/* iPad Portrait
======================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  .click {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 2%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="primary-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item">Home
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="sub-item">menu1</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu2</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">About us</li>
    <li class="menu-item">Service
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="sub-item">menu1</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu2</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">product</li>
    <li class="menu-item">packages</li>
    <li class="menu-item">contact</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu7</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu8</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu9</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu10</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu11
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="sub-item">menu1</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu2</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu12</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu13</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu14
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="sub-item">menu1</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu2</li>
        <li class="sub-item">menu3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="click"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you observe on desktop mode also some menu items hidden and red button appear. Desktop mode I don't want the red button or menu-items hidden.

Comment: On desktop mode upto menu 10 is visible not all other than this everything working fine what I want.